# MIPI interface to FPGA pins

Tags: fpga

I need to interface a MIPI output from a device to an FPGA. I don't have a lot informations about MIPI output, so I suppose it's most standard possible and works on 3.3v. MIPI should run at max 80Mhz and it's only output to FPGA.

Since I'm new with MIPI interfaces, and I didn't find pratical explainations on google, I want to ask:

- Which hardware (between MIPI and FPGA) I need and how I should interface MIPI to FPGA?

ex.
Should I use Pull-UP, Pull-DOWN or inductance matching resistors?
Should I apply a particular layout to this lanes?
Should I connect either Positive and Negative channels or only one Channel or use a particular device?

Comment: Which MIPI type interface? There are several. What are you trying to interface with? If there are P and N signals, then it is differential and not a 3.3V single-ended standard.

Comment: Never assume anything when it comes to voltage standards...

Comment: Also, "inductance matching resistors" is not a thing.